# strange behavior of setCompletionBlock in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

```cs
GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *filter;
GPUImageMovieWriter *movieWriter;
.
.
.
__block BOOL finished = NO;
__weak id weakMovieWriter = movieWriter;
[movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Completed Successfully");
    __strong id strongMovieWritier = weakMovieWriter;
    [strongMovieWritier finishRecording];
    [filter removeTarget:strongMovieWritier];
    finished = YES;
    NSLog(finished ? @"Yes" : @"No");

}];
while (!finished);
[self completeTransaction]; // this method is not executed!!!
```

Concerning the above code the method [self completeTransaction] is not executed, even when i know the variable "finished" is changed to YES.

But if i change this piece of code

```
while (!finished);
```

to

```cs
while (!finished){
    NSLog(@"Whatever");
}
```

The method [self completeTransaction] is called.

Anybody know why this happens?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why you don't put `[self completeTransaction];` inside completion block and replace `self` for `weakself`?, I think is a better approach

Answer (score 0):

reviewing again your code I think if

```
[self completeTransaction];
```

executes is rare because the completion block

```
[movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Completed Successfully");
    __strong id strongMovieWritier = weakMovieWriter;
    [strongMovieWritier finishRecording];
    [filter removeTarget:strongMovieWritier];
    finished = YES;
    NSLog(finished ? @"Yes" : @"No");

}];
```

executes a-synchronically and your `[self completeTransaction];` I assume that execute on main thread, I recommend you to do this

```
GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *filter;
GPUImageMovieWriter *movieWriter;
.
.
.
__weak id weakMovieWriter = movieWriter;
__weak weakSelf = self;
[movieWriter setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"Completed Successfully");
    __strong id strongMovieWritier = weakMovieWriter;
    [strongMovieWritier finishRecording];
    [filter removeTarget:strongMovieWritier];
    [weakSelf completeTransaction];
}];
```

instead as I said on my previous comment, Hope this helps you

Comment: thanks Reinier.
I know how to solve this problem.
I want know why it happens!

Comment: check my answer again, I think that this happens because misuse of  threads, your completion block executes in one thread and your `[self completeTransaction];`in another, i hope this clarifies you

Answer (score 0):

Your `while (!finished);` will suck up all the run cycles, effectively blocking your thread. You have to return from your code so the runloop and other things (including your completion block) can run.  I'm late to the party here, but this answers your question.